# Anorm Scala Difference between executeUpdate and executeInsert

Tags: scala, anorm

I've been wracking my head over the difference between using `executeUpdate()` as opposed to `executeInsert()`.

In the following code, I used `executeInsert()`

```
def addEntry(day: DateMidnight, create_time: DateTime, points: Long, src: String) = DB.withTransaction { implicit connection => 

    Logger.debug("I got here")
    SQL(
      """
        INSERT INTO density_cache(day_of, create_time, points, src) 
           VALUES ({day_of}, {create_time}, {points}, {src})
      """
    ).on(
      'day_of       -> day,
      'create_time  -> create_time,
      'points       -> points,
      'src          -> src
    ).executeInsert()
    Logger.debug("Got to 2nd step")
}
```

I get the following problem:
Java.lang.RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 2013-04-15 13:58:46.0:class java.sql.Timestamp to Long for column ColumnName(density_cache.day_of,Some(day_of)))

But when I switch to `executeUpdate()`, it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `executeInsert` will return the auto-generated key (if there is one).

[Anorm, simple SQL data access => Executing SQL queries](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaAnorm)

> If you are inserting data that has an auto-generated `Long` primary key, you can call `executeInsert()`. If you have more than one generated key, or it is not a Long, `executeInsert` can be passed a `ResultSetParser` to return the correct key.

In your case I guess/assume that you don't have an auto-incremented primary key and therefor it won't work with the `executeInsert()`. If you have then you may have to pass a `ResultSetParser` with the correct type.